# How to use this JSON with the hierarchy layout?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, force-layout

I got this JSON data below which contains nodes and links. Now, my problem is this: I use the hierarchy layout in d3. Usually this hierarchy layout needs a JSON input data, that contains only the nodes. And the links can get generated by

```
hierarchy.links().
```

But in my case blow, the links are also a part on the JSON data. Can anyone help?

```
       "Nodes": [
            {
              "Id": "338",
              "Name": "TEST NODE ONE",
              "Url": "http://www.google.com"
            },
            {
              "Id": "340",
              "Name": "TEST NODE TWO",
              "Url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
            },

          ]
         "links": [
            {
              "source": 0,
              "target": 0,
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "source": 0,
              "target": 1,
              "value": "0"
            },


          ]
```